# Lock screen GPO is not applied to client servers of ActiveDirectory?

Tags: active-directory, gpo

Lockscreen policy setup in Active directory, but it's not reflecting to the client servers (window 10/11).

Steps followed:

1. Lockscreen image is in AD server which can be accessible by network path (UNC path).
   <kbd>Note:</kbd> I can able to access the lockscreen image in the client machine with the network path of the image.
2. Created the Group Policy - in `Computer Configuration > Policies > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization > Force a specific default lock screen image`, enabled it and given the network path of the image.

Why is the policy not applying to the client servers? am i missing any Steps here?

What I tried:

1. force the policy by the below command,
   `gpupdate /force`

Outcome of what I did:

1. In AD server the lockscreen is changed to what I have set but not in the client's servers.
2. when I run `gpresult /r`, it doesn't list the policy name of the lockscreen.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: You need to link the GPO to a target OU where the servers reside, otherwise they won't know to apply it. `Get-GPO "Name of the GPO you created" |New-GPLink -Target "OU=containing,OU=the,OU=servers,DC=domain,DC=tld" -LinkEnabled Yes`

Comment: Thanks for the response, how to check if that's enabled or not?

Comment: In the Group Policy Management Console (`gpmc.msc`): Go to `Group Policy Management -> Forest: [forest root fqdn] -> Domains -> [your domain fqdn] -> Group Policy Objects`. Select the GPO in question, and the right-hand pane will show all existing links and whether they're enabled. If using PowerShell, do `Get-GPO <name of GPO> |Get-GPLink`

Comment: Yes, its enabled. where there is a column called "Link Enable" and valued as "yes".

Comment: And the OU it's linked to is the OU that contains the server(s) in question? If so, check the ACL (the security permissions) on the GPO - make sure that the servers in question have access to read and apply the GPO. Next troubleshooting step would be running `gpresult` with `/z` instead of `/r`

Comment: i have another policy which is applied as same as the lockscreen policy and its working as excepted. But the lockscreen policy is not, and i have used the commands `gpresult /z` and `gpresult /r`, but the lockscreen policy is not list here.